# Hiding an option value based on first dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

I would like to hide an option value if one value is selected in first dropdown.
I have added below the dropdown code:

```
<select name="time_hour" class="span6">
    <option value="00" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '00'){ echo "selected";} ?>>00</option>
    <option value="01" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '01'){ echo "selected";} ?>>01</option>
    <option value="02" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '02'){ echo "selected";} ?>>02</option>
    <option value="03" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '03'){ echo "selected";} ?>>03</option>
    <option value="04" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '04'){ echo "selected";} ?>>04</option>
    <option value="05" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '05'){ echo "selected";} ?>>05</option>
    <option value="06" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '06'){ echo "selected";} ?>>06</option>
    <option value="07" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '07'){ echo "selected";} ?>>07</option>
    <option value="08" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '08'){ echo "selected";} ?>>08</option>
    <option value="09" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '09'){ echo "selected";} ?>>09</option>
    <option value="10" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '10'){ echo "selected";} ?>>10</option>
    <option value="11" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '11'){ echo "selected";} ?>>11</option>
    <option value="12" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '12'){ echo "selected";} ?>>12</option>
    <option value="13" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '13'){ echo "selected";} ?>>13</option>
    <option value="14" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '14'){ echo "selected";} ?>>14</option>
    <option value="15" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '15'){ echo "selected";} ?>>15</option>
    <option value="16" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '16'){ echo "selected";} ?>>16</option>
    <option value="17" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '17'){ echo "selected";} ?>>17</option>
    <option value="18" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '18'){ echo "selected";} ?>>18</option>
    <option value="19" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '19'){ echo "selected";} ?>>19</option>
    <option value="20" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '20'){ echo "selected";} ?>>20</option>
    <option value="21" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '21'){ echo "selected";} ?>>21</option>
    <option value="22" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '22'){ echo "selected";} ?>>22</option>
    <option value="23" <?php if(date('H',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == '23'){ echo "selected";} ?>>23</option>
                                        </select>
```

And the second dropdown is

```
<select name="time_min" id="time_min" class="span6">
    <option value="00" <?php if(date('i',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == 00){ echo "selected";} ?>>00</option>
    <option value="15" <?php if(date('i',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == 15){ echo "selected";} ?>>15</option>
    <option value="30" <?php if(date('i',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == 30){ echo "selected";} ?>>30</option>
    <option value="45" <?php if(date('i',strtotime($time_gap[0]->time_gap_time)) == 45){ echo "selected";} ?>>45</option>
                                        </select>
```

So, for example, If I select 00 in first dropdown, 00 should be hide in second dropdown. I am trying to get this possibility. Please help.

Comment: Show the code you have tried?

Comment: First of all, you really should use [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) for printing `<option>`s. Secondly, where is your JS?

Comment: Surely 00:00 and 15:15 are both valid hour,minute combinations. Where's the logic behind treating them as invalid combinations with JavaScript? Are you sure you want the behavior for both 15:15 and 00:00, or are you just trying to simulate a placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery and set `id="time_hour"` attribute for first select tag:

```
    $("#time_hour").change(function (){
      $("#time_min").find("option").css('display','')
      $("#time_min").find("option[value="+$(this).val()+"]").css('display','none')
    });
```